# PageBreak in ReportLab package Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, package, reportlab

I created a table containing data and I need to download it as pdf. With the below code I am getting the first page of data only. I want the continuation of data to be in the second page.

```
def save_data_to_pdf(colModel, colData, file_path, reportName):
    
    buffer = BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF canvas with landscape orientation
    c = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=landscape(A4))
    
    # Extract the column headers from colModel
    column_names = [column['label'] for column in colModel]
    
    # Define table data
    table_data = [column_names]# Header row
    for row_data in colData:
        row = [row_data.get(column['name'], '') for column in colModel]
        table_data.append(row)
    # Define table style
    
    table_style = TableStyle([
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.grey),
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 10),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 2),
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.beige),
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.black),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
        ('COLWIDTH', (0, 0), (1, 1), [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 5]),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),    
    ])
    
    # Create the table and apply style
    table = Table(table_data)
    table.setStyle(table_style)
    
    # Calculate the available space on the page
    page_width, page_height = landscape(A4)
    margin = 10  # Adjust the margin as needed
    available_width = page_width - (5 * margin)
    available_height = page_height - (5 * margin)

    # Wrap the table within the available space
    table.wrapOn(c, available_width, available_height)

    # Calculate the table width and height
    table_width, table_height = table.wrap(5, 5)  # 0, 0 indicates no additional wrapping needed

    # Calculate the position to center the table vertically
    bottom_margin = margin  # Desired bottom margin
    vertical_margin = 300 - 600
    # Draw the table on the canvas with the adjusted vertical position
    table.drawOn(c, margin, vertical_margin)
    
    # Save the canvas content
    c.save()
    
    # Write the buffer content to a PDF file
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(buffer.getvalue())
```